# How to ignore request using interceptors based on request content?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

How can I return a status `200` and abort the controller call if a specific key on the request payload matches my requirements?

I'm using [Interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) on my application, but I couldn't figure out how to return a status "200" without throwing an exception.

Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler<any>,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const { data } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body as Message;
    const payload: InputData = JSON.parse(data.toString());

    if (payload.order.payment.type === 'MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE') {
      // How to return a success and abort the controller call?
      throw new HttpException(
        {
          message:
            'payment type is not supported, this message will be ignored.',
        },
        200,
      );
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler<any>,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const { data } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body as Message;
    const payload: InputData = JSON.parse(data.toString());

    if (payload.order.payment.type === 'MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE') {
      // How to return a success and abort the controller call?
      const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse<Response>();
      // depending on the underlying HTTP engine (express or fastify or other) this might need to be modified
      response.statusCode = 200;
      return of({
        message: 'payment type is not supported, this message will be ignored.' 
      });
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

and the interceptor will return that early instead of calling to your controller. `of` is an Observable creation operator from the `rxjs` package

Comment: the default http status is 200?

Comment: For `GET`? Yeah. POST is `201`, but you can get the response and set the status code as necessary

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example on how to set the status code?